# Android Raspberry Pi Gstreamer not showing proper video

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, gstreamer

In order to stream live video from Raspberry Pi Cam to Android device I installed GStreamer 1.0 in Raspberry Pi. Then following this link
[Gstreamer in Android. UDP stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511765/gstreamer-in-android-udp-stream?rq=1)

Executed the server and client side, but the output in the android device is coming like the screenshot given below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYTHH.png

Please advice what am I doing wrong or missing. Is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks

Raspberry Pi Server:

```
raspivid -t 999999 -h 240 -w 320 -fps 25 -b 2000000 -o - | 
gst-launch-1.0 -v     fdsrc fd=0 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! 
udpsink host=192.168.42.43 port=5000
```

Android Client:

```
data->pipeline = gst_parse_launch("udpsrc port=5000 caps=\"application/x-rtp,
media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264,
sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\\\"J2QAFKwrQLj/LwDxImo\\\\=\\\\,KO4fLA\\\\=\\\\=\\\"\",
ssrc=(uint)2607831725, clock-base=(uint)1706962490, seqnum-base=(uint)15791,
payload=(int)96\" ! queue ! rtph264depay ! queue ! 
ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink sync=false", &error);
```

**EDIT**
We are following Example-3 of GStreamer Android Guide.
http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Android+tutorial+3%3A+Video
Replaced Line 159 of the tutorial-3.c file with the above line mentioned under Android Client

Comment: we tried with fps as 15 its still the same thing... @greenapps

Comment: Where is that Android code line called? Why do you give so little info?

Comment: Can you format that line please so we dont have to scroll half an hour? Both please.

Comment: @greenapps i have added the example from where the android lines are taken and sorry for the poor formatting..

Comment: How do you connect? B!uetooth, wifi, lan cable?

Comment: @greenapps the android device is connected to the raspberry pi via wifi...

Comment: Android is hot spot? You dont use a router? `Why do you give so little info?`.

Comment: the raspberry pi itself is the wifi router ., the android device is connected to the raspberry pi via wifi. please do let me know what details you want.

Comment: At the moment i can not help you with examining as i have no camera module yet. Will order one.

Comment: It came in today. Now wait for a rainy sunday afternoon so i can try it out ;-).

Comment: @greenapps thanks for your help i have already solved the issue once i am finished with the work i will upload the details thanks

Comment: Well thats very nice of you. And i fear you will forget...